# How can I centre an input element in Angular?

Tags: angular

i am  learning Angular and i have tried several times with online suggestions on how to centre  an input  element  without sucess.Can anyone please  help?

This  is  for me to learn Angular .I am using  Angular  7.I have  tried  to  use  Flexbox  CSS and normal  CSS but  the  Input  always  show on  the top left corner of the page.

```
input {
 text-align: center;
 border: 3px solid green;
 }

 #textboxid
{
   height:40px;
   width: 400px;
   font-size:20pt;
}

<input
   (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)"  id=textboxid  class="container" >

   <ul *ngIf="results">
     <li *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:9">
       <a href="{{ result.latest }}" target="_blank">
         {{ result.name }}
       </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

stackblizdemo: https://angular-wv4nt9.stackblitz.io

Comment: can you please provide `stackblitz`  demo

Comment: thanks @ram12393...above is my  demo  please  check

Comment: I have created, please check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxkpgd) based on your given code.

Basically to use flexbox you need a container as `flex` and set `justify-content` to `center`

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Here's a fun flexbox tutorial and to learn https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: thank you @penleychan...one last  qn.how  can i  centre  verticallly and horizontally?right now the  code yoy provide  it just  centre  horizontally only

Comment: @FrankD., I updated the stackblitz example. What you need to do is set the height of `html, body` to 100% and your `container` to 100% and `align-items: center;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `input` into `div`.

```
<div class="search-box">
<input
   (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)"  id=textboxid  class="container" >
</div>
```

and css

```
.search-box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ru1cnn)